# Why does my cat always bring me his toy when I'm brushing teeth in the bathroom?

Tags: cats, toys

I know that bringing me his toy is a sign of attention-seeking, but why does he always do this when I'm brushing my teeth in the bathroom, not when I ignore him while doing other things like using my computer etc. Sometimes he brings me his toy when I'm using the toilet as well, but not as often as when I'm brushing teeth.

Comment: what do you do when your cat bring you the toy,how do you react.the thing with cats are they learn from experience so your cat makes some sort of connection and bring you the toy when  you brush your teeth.

Comment: @trondhansen that. Cat sauntered in, toy in tow, and the asker e.g. threw the toy. Lightbulb moment - rinse, repeat and confirm that humans that are brushing their teeth are up for a game of fetch.

Comment: I don't think I've been reinforcing the behavior. I only pick up the toy and put it back outside when I'm done brushing my teeth and leave the bathroom. However outside the bathroom we can play with the toy for tens of minutes.

Comment: I think this behavior may somehow relate to him considering the bathroom a dangerous place, but I don't know how exactly

Comment: It could have to do with the running water: a lot of cats like to drink from the sink. But in this particular case, it may just be that Cats Are Funny. :-)